# is there any other way to allow dash in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using this code but for it i have to write it gradually all links into my config file. is there any other better way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

That's how my code look like

controller:

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class Drink_cola extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("header.php");
        $this->load->view("abc.php");
        $this->load->view("footer.php");
    }

}

?>
```

and one thing i am doing in routes.php to allow dash is this:

routes.php

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
$route['Drink-cola'] ='Drink_cola';
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @tilz0R i am asking for other options.

Comment: if i copy your class into my project folder - it works like a charm

Comment: i tried your class and it works as expected - so whats your result if you call /drink-cola/ ?

Comment: i never said that this code is not working, i am just saying is there any other way to perform this activity.

Comment: what i meant - i tried this code without your custom route and it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is. Write the following in your /application/config/routes.php:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;
```

This exact topic is documented [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=translate_uri_dashes).

Comment: i had done this but it is not working on multiple url parameters e.g: ex.com/drink-cola

Comment: which version of CI are u using ?

Comment: 3.1.5. Current Version

Answer (score 0):

Open file `/application/config/routes.php` and add the following line in the route array:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

It will automatically translate your MY_CONTROLLER to MY-CONTROLLER or in small letters.

Comment: i had done this but it is not working on multiple url parameters e.g: ex.com/drink-cola

Comment: you need to pass the values like the following                                                                                                                      $route['com/drink-cola']='Maincontroller';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
I can assure you it will work

Comment: i know, but isn't there any other options?

Comment: you can also use the following for dynamic routing                                                                   $route[':any/:any']='Maincontroller';                                                                                               
If you enter the following url then the result can be achieved                                       http://localhost/testci/com/drink-cola